# Memory Allocation for a Triple Pointer that Points to a Dynamic 2D Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

For my C programming class, we have to code a void function that has a file, char*** array, and int* variable as inputs. We're supposed to go through the file, determine the number of lines and store that in the int* variable and then copy each individual line into a corresponding line in the char*** array.

I managed to get a copy of each line from the file into a char** array and now I need to have the char*** array point to this char** array. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with this part.

If I try to display the lines of the char** array, everything works fine. However, if I try to display the lines of the char*** array after linking it to the char** array, the first line is displayed and then a segmentation fault occurs.

Here's code for the last part, where array is the char*** variable, array2 is the char** variable, and num is the int* variable that has the number of lines in the file:

```
array = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**));

array = &array2;

for(i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", *array[i]);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm handling the memory allocation wrong, but I could be wrong. All code before this point seems to work perfectly fine though.

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit: This may or may not be important, but in the main function, the char*** array is actually a char** array but when using the function, it is entered as &array, making it char***.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to modify `array` since that points to a variable in the calling function.  Instead, you want to dereference `array` and assign it malloc'ed memory for an array of pointers.

Let's say you have `num` lines in the file.  First create an array of pointers:

```
*array = malloc(num * sizeof(char *));    // Don't cast the return value of malloc
```

Then for each line, allocate space for the line:

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    char line[250];
    // read the line into "line"
    (*array)[i] = strdup(line);   // Note the parenthesis
}
```

If you want to use `char **array2` to make things look cleaner, you want to assign its value to what `array` points to instead of making `array` point to the address of `array2`:

```
char **array2 = malloc(num * sizeof(char *));
*array = array2;
...
for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    char line[250];
    // read the line into "line"
    array2[i] = strdup(line);
}
```